# What is the purpose of * in the ReaderT Monad Transformer?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am looking at [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html) for the [Reader monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#t:Reader) and [ReaderT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#t:ReaderT) monad transformer.

The relevant definitions are:

```
newtype ReaderT k r m a :: forall k. * -> (k -> *) -> k -> *
type Reader r = ReaderT * r Identity
```

I don't understand what the `*` are doing in the definitions.  In particular I am attempting to derive a new monad from ReaderT with IO as the base monad and a class constraint on the `r` value.

I am not sure why there is a fourth input to ReaderT (`k`) and what Reader is doing with that value when it puts a * in that position.

Comment: Note that the source code for `ReaderT` is `newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }`. The `k` is only generated in the documentation by Haddock to emphasize the poly-kindedness of `ReaderT` (`-XPolyKinds` is enabled in the module where it is defined).

Comment: "I am attempting to derive a new monad from ReaderT with IO as the base monad and a class constraint on the r value" - while this is likely to cause more problems than it solves (the placing of a constraint on the `r` value, not the derivation of a new type from `ReaderT` with `m` instantiated to `IO`) I don't see why doing this would be impeded by the polykinded definition of `ReaderT`. As @Alec states, the `k` parameter is an artifact of haddock - in reality, it is entirely implicit, and you can pretend that `ReaderT :: (* -> *) -> * -> *` (because it does indeed have that type).

Comment: @user2407038 and nicolas You are both correct.  The constraint belonged and is now placed on an instance declaration not the monad definition.

Comment: @Alec, I think this is the real answer to my question. (Make it an answer instread of a comment and I'll accept it.) As a follow up where did the type constructor and the field name disappear to in the documentation.  Those are useful to know.

Comment: I'm hoping someday Haddock will put kind arguments in curly braces or something like that (or maybe prefix them with `@`). It can get confusing to read the kind arguments and type arguments together (I guess `TypeInType` might blur things a bit though).

Comment: @JohnF.Miller I can see both the constructor and field name [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#t:ReaderT). Where do you find that it is omitted? (If you do not see it there, you should - I can only guess that there is something strange going on with your browser).

Comment: @JohnF.Miller I recommend you just ask the existing answerer to modify his answer to mention Haddock. I reckon most people who stumble on this question will probably see my comment anyways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` is the kind of types with values : it stands for things like `Int`, `List Int` etc..

`forall k` means `k` is not necessarily of that kind. it stands for any kind of types, viewed as simply static things which you can declare and manipulate, but are not necessarily associated with runtime values. One example of this is when you want to 'decorate' some other type with extra information : the embroidering type has no reason to have any sort of value attached to it, it is "pure" information, to some embroided type (which usually have values)

More simply here, you can see that in `Reader` it all gets specialized to `*`, and `m` is specialised to the `Identity` monad. That's where you'd want your `IO` monad to be.

As for the constraints, it is best to not specify it in the type itself. Upon usage, where you use a particular method attached to the typeclass, it will get added on the fly. Indeed there are no reason expressions written which do not use a method should be burdened by requiring their callers to provide it.

(Unless you have a very good reason to, for deducing other instances, as in `Dict` where you capture a typeclass witness as a runtime value with a GADT, but that's probably not what you want to do)

Comment: You are correct. The constraint belonged and is now placed on an instance declaration not the monad definition.